# Error: XML Content does not seem to be XML

Tags: r, xml

[image]

I am trying to get this XML file, but am unable to. I checked the other solutions in the same topic, but I couldn't understand. I am a R newbie.

```
fileUrl <- "https://www.espn.in/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE)
```

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: "https://www.espn.in/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens"
Can you please help?

Comment: That URL goes to a dense dashboard of data. When I run a browser dev-console on that, I don't see any XML data in the entire stream of secondary network connections. What makes you think that that URL houses an XML document?

Comment: I have added an image to tell you that what am  I trying to achieve. @r2evans

Answer (score 0):

According to the xml file in your error message, try this:

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
url <--"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
r = GET(url)
doc <- xmlTreeParse(r, useInternal=TRUE)
```